# Downloading a Blob using java gives me a huge file

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Here's the blob information:

Blob{bucket=some_bucket, name=somefile-000000000001.json.gz, generation=1539720839099466, size=42455994, content-type=application/octet-stream, metadata=null}

somefile-...json.gz is a dump from BigQuery (totally ~4gig when you add all the files)

As you can tell the size is about 42megs. But when I do blob.downloadTo(...file) it runs and run and it can easily get to the >300 gigabyte size and seem like it could run forever... this seems odd to me as it's just about the same code than the google examples.

Interesting facts worth nothing:

- The dump from bigquery to storage creates 122 files ~40meg each which totals ~5gb compressed when you add them all up... which confuses me since our download is 56gb compressed compared to the sum of all files.
- Our BigQuery table size is 19.08 GB

Anyone has any idea?

Sample of the code to dump to our bucket

```
    String bucketUrl = "gs://" + BUCKET_NAME + "/"+table.getDataset()+"/"+filename+"-*." + EXPORT_EXTENSION;

    log.info("Exporting table " + table.getTable() + " to " + bucketUrl);
    ExtractJobConfiguration extractConfiguration = ExtractJobConfiguration.newBuilder(table, bucketUrl)
        .setCompression(EXPORT_COMPRESSION)
        .setFormat(EXPORT_FORMAT)
        .build();

    Job job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(extractConfiguration));
    try {
        // Wait for the job to complete
        Job completedJob = job.waitFor(RetryOption.initialRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)),
                RetryOption.totalTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3)));
        if (completedJob != null && completedJob.getStatus().getError() == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            log.error(completedJob.getStatus().getError());
            throw new BigQueryException(1, "Unable to complete the export", completedJob.getStatus().getError());
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return false;
```

and the code to download (where blob = Blob{bucket=some_bucket, name=somefile-000000000001.json.gz, generation=1539720839099466, size=42455994, content-type=application/octet-stream, metadata=null} )

```
    Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, srcFilename));
    blob.downloadTo(destFilePath);
```

Comment: I've just tried to replicate your scenario, by doing a BigQuery export (7gig+ table), then downloading one of the files with the `blob.downloadTo(destFilePath);` code, but the file was compressed. Can you explain how are you doing the BigQuery dump? If it's possible, include your code

Comment: @F10 thanks for the reply! Our process is as follow:
- Take a subset of an existing 3rd party bigquery table
- Take that new BigQuery table and export it to our bucket

I have updated the question with the step taking our bigquery table and exporting it! :)

Comment: I'm attaching my code on an answer

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following code and I successfully did the export and could downloaded the files compressed:

```
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.ExtractJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates clients
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    TableId table = TableId.of("dataset","table");
    // The name for the new bucket
    String bucketName = "bucket";
    ExtractJobConfiguration extractConfiguration = ExtractJobConfiguration.newBuilder(table, "gs://"+bucketName+"/somefile-*.json.gz")
        .setCompression("GZIP")
        .setFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON")
        .build();
    Job startedJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(extractConfiguration));
        // Wait for the job to complete
    while(!startedJob.isDone()){
        System.out.println("Waiting for job " + startedJob.getJobId().getJob() + " to complete");
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
    if (startedJob.getStatus().getError() == null) {
        System.out.println("Job " + startedJob.getJobId().getJob() + " succeeded");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Job " + startedJob.getJobId().getJob() + " failed");
        System.out.println("Error: " + startedJob.getStatus().getError());
    }
    Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
    Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();
    System.out.println("Downloading");
    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + blob.getName());
        System.out.println("Size: " + blob.getSize());
        Path destFilePath = Paths.get(blob.getName());
        blob.downloadTo(destFilePath);
    }
  }
}
```

pom.xml file dependencies I've used are the following:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
 <version>1.38.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
 <version>1.48.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.